# MYSQL, I want to use a multiplication operator on a entire column

Tags: mysql

I have a table product, in this table I have column for `sale_price` which indicates how much we are selling the product for. I want to multiply that entire column by 10% and then update that information in my table.

Comment: `update product set sale_price = sale_price * 0.1;`

Comment: Thank you so much, it work. I really appreciate the help this site brings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE product 
SET sale_price = sale_price * 1.10
```